# TypeDescriptor replacement in PCL

Tags: c#, type-conversion, portable-class-library, typedescriptor

`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type)` is [a very convientent way](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx) to serialize/deserialize lots of built-in data types to/from strings:

```
object original = ...;

string serialized = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t).ConvertToInvariantString(original);
object deserialized = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t).ConvertFromInvariantString(serialized);
```

Unfortunately, `TypeDescriptor` is not available in portable class libraries.

Is there a canonical replacement or do we have to go back to huge switch statements?

Comment: @S.Akbari: Thanks, I have seen it. I'd like to keep the question open for the moment just in case someone else *did* find a suitable workaround.

Comment: Based on the view count of the post I doubt even if there is a workaround someone find this post and post it. But I believe your question is a good one and it deserve more viewer and votes and also it may be suitable for future visitors. I suggest that you place a bounty on it so that you will draw attention to your question.

Answer (score 2):

`TypeDescriptor` is not available in PCLs, but it might be available on the actual client *using* the PCL.

This is the workaround I used to inject the Mono TypeDescriptor from a Xamarin Android project:

PCL:

```
public interface IPclWorkaround
{
    ConvertFromInvariantString(Type type, string s);
}
```

Xamarin Android:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PclWorkaround))]

class PclWorkaround : IPclWorkaround
{
    public object ConvertFromInvariantString(Type type, string s)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).ConvertFromInvariantString(s);
    }
}
```

Usage in PCL:

```
var myObject = DependencyService.Get<IPclWorkaround>.ConvertFromInvariantString(type, myString);
```

Comment: Great workaround, I haven't tried that, would be nice if you can indicate what PCL profile you were on, and what platforms you succeeded implementing this `IPclWorkaround` interface and get it to work using the local system tools.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, fortunately [this is covered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netstandard-2.0&term=typedescriptor) in .NET Standard 2.0.
.Net Standard 1.4 is already accessible using XF (Xamarin Forms). Hopefully, real soon (vNext), with the official release of 2.0, Mono and in turn XF.iOS, XF.Droid, XF.Mac and UWP, will also join the party and all those missing APIs will be available in XF, as seen in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-platforms-support) table.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `TypeDescriptor` in PCL projects because it is not built as a PCL and it is not cross platform. The `TypeDescriptor` is unavailable in PCL projects and it is not listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

The following assemblies are available within a Portable Class Library project:

> • `mscorlib.dll`
>
> • `System.dll`
>
> • `System.Core.dll`
>
> • `System.Xml.dll`
>
> • `System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll`
>
> • `System.Net.dll`
>
> • `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`
>
> • `System.ServiceModel.dll`
>
> • `System.Xml.Serialization.dll`
>
> • `System.Windows.dll (from Silverlight)`

Comment: Ask for `replacement`

Comment: @Cologler There is actually no alternative and replacement to `TypeDescriptor`. Serializing frameworks relying on `TypeDescriptor` are currently not portable.

Comment: I recommend that you link to a more recent version of the Portable Class Library development page, like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) one. The page for VS 2010 is severely outdated.